# What is wrong with this vector comparison?

Tags: c++

I am trying to compare a vector before a method to the same vector after a method to assert that they are the same vector but when I run my test, I get the following errors:

```
[build] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\xutility(5044,1): error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::equal_to<void>::operator ()(_Ty1 &&,_Ty2 &&) noexcept(<expr>) const' [C:\Users\james\Documents\BSc Computer Science\4007CEM - Activity Led Learning\FantasyRPG\build\tests\test_containers.vcxproj]
[build] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\xstddef(198): message : see declaration of 'std::equal_to<void>::operator ()' [C:\Users\james\Documents\BSc Computer Science\4007CEM - Activity Led Learning\FantasyRPG\build\tests\test_containers.vcxproj]
[build] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\xutility(5044,1): message : With the following template arguments: [C:\Users\james\Documents\BSc Computer Science\4007CEM - Activity Led Learning\FantasyRPG\build\tests\test_containers.vcxproj]
[build] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\xutility(5044,1): message : '_Ty1=const Item &' [C:\Users\james\Documents\BSc Computer Science\4007CEM - Activity Led Learning\FantasyRPG\build\tests\test_containers.vcxproj]
[build] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\xutility(5044,1): message : '_Ty2=const Item &' [C:\Users\james\Documents\BSc Computer Science\4007CEM - Activity Led Learning\FantasyRPG\build\tests\test_containers.vcxproj]
[build] Build finished with exit code 1
```

I have narrowed the bug down to one line of code which is as follows:

```
REQUIRE(contentsBefore == merchant.get_contents());
```

The method `get_contents` is defined `std::vector<Item> get_contents() {return contents;}` and should return a vector of objects of type `Item`.
In greater context, this is the block of code around the erroneous line:

```
WHEN("I try to add something which is not an Item.") {
    std::vector<Item> contentsBefore = merchant.get_contents();
    merchant.addItem(helmet);
    THEN("The container should not be updated to add the item.") {
        REQUIRE(contentsBefore == merchant.get_contents());
    }
}
```

The code compiles fine with the line in question commented out, so I am thinking that the `==` operation is illegal here for some reason, which the error seems to suggest too (`'unknown-type std::equal_to<void>::operator ()(_Ty1 &&,_Ty2 &&) noexcept(<expr>) const'`), but I'm able to use it to compare vectors in a piece of test code so am not sure why this is happening.

I have also tried to reword the code as follows:

```
WHEN("I try to add something which is not an Item.") {
    std::vector<Item> contentsBefore = merchant.get_contents();
    merchant.addItem(helmet);
    std::vector<Item> contentsAfter = merchant.get_contents();
    THEN("The container should not be updated to add the item.") {
        REQUIRE(contentsBefore == contentsAfter);
    }
}
```

But this did not resolve the issue, so I really don't understand what the issue is. `contents` is a private attribute but I don't see that this would be the issue as the `get_contents` method is working fine in the line where `contentsBefore` is defined...

Comment: What is `REQUIRE`? Possibly you just need to make `get_contents` a const member function.

Comment: ... and `WHEN` and `THEN` is unfamiliar to too.

Comment: REQUIRE / THEN / WHEN is BDD syntax from Catch2 testing, but isn't the issue I don't think as I've got half a dozen other tests using it which work fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message suggests that your object Item is not implementing operator==

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/equal_to

```
template< class T >
struct equal_to; //(until C++14)
template< class T = void > struct equal_to; //(since C++14)
```

Function object for performing comparisons. Unless specialised, invokes operator== on type T.

Comment: But I'm comparing vectors, not the objects of my own class

Comment: You can't compare two vectors without also comparing the elements inside them

Comment: so what's the difference between this and `vector<int> vec = {1}; vector<int> vec2 = {1}; if (vec == vec2) {std::cout << "same";}` as that's what I did to check whether vectors are comparable and that worked fine?

Comment: @askman If you want to compare the vectors in some way without comparing the objects of your class contained in those vectors, you will have to overload the `==` operator yourself.

Comment: @askman `std::vector<int>` is a vector of ints. You can compare ints directly because `operator==` is defined for them. You need to define `operator==` for `Item` in order to compare two `Item`s or `Item` vectors.

Comment: yep, I get it now, I had the exact same issue yesterday and should have learned. Thanks all!